# SQL join two similar tables

Tags: sql, db2, union, union-all

I have two similar tables:

```
SELECT * FROM CTP0002;

SDKEY      SDNAME
2          Hello
4          World


SELECT * FROM CTP0003;

SSKEY      SSNAME
3          Name1
6          Name2
```

And i want this result:

```
SDKEY      SDNAME
2          Hello
4          World
3          Name1
6          Name2
```

I tried to join it, but that doesn't work.

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: Can you tell us why you need a `full outer join`?

Comment: use union [click here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms180026.aspx)

Comment: I thought I need full outer join to get the hole content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM CTP0002;
union all
SELECT * FROM CTP0003;
```